# UIButton turnover animation

Tags: ios

Do any of you know how I could possibly add an animation that is triggered when a UIButton is pressed, and the UIButton turns aand enlarges at the same time, and on the other side I can show another view? A bit like in dashboard on a Mac, with the info button on the widgets...

Comment: Hey Alessandro, you could always put your information on another view and then use the modal flip transition to navigate the that view... That will give the effect of the widgets on dashboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transitions:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{

    buttonView.hidden = YES;
    otherView1.hidden = NO;
    otherView2.hidden = NO;
    otherViewEtc.hidden = NO;

} completion:nil];
```

You would then have a `containerView` which contains the flip button and the alternate view hidden, and in the transition, you can hide the first view and show the alternate view...